# How to get alerts at client side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set an alert service for my website users for there tasks.

These alerts are like Messenger alerts. My web site is in asp.net C#.

Here is the scenario I want to set for alerts:

I retrieve the alert messages for users through a webservice 
and I want utility which displays alerts for users at client site.

Can anyone help me to sort out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html) works and is free

Comment: Yes, it works with ASP.NET and it's all contained within your JavaScript.  A Web Service is not going to do anything for you when it comes to displaying the actual alert in the UI.  Your Web Service is just the component that should be retrieving information.

Comment: Thanks deadbug for the solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd party which is not free : http://www.intersoftpt.com/WebDesktop/Notification

Comment: Thanks,
Actually I dont want to use third party. I want to create using asp.net c#. If you have solution please provide.